# Error when I deploy Firebase Cloud function in Bitbucket pipeline

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, bitbucket-pipelines

Recently, I was having a problem with the pipeline on Bitbucket. Everything was good until it showed me a "Deployment error".

> Build failed: Build error details not available. Please check the logs
> at [https://console.cloud.google.com/........"](https://console.cloud.google.com/........%22)

The error shown in Google Cloud is:

> "ERROR: error fetching storage source: generic::unknown: retry budget
> exhausted (3 attempts): fetching gcs source: unpacking source from
> gcs: source fetch container exited with non-zero status: 1"

That error is pretty new. I didn't have this error yesterday and I haven't updated any library since then.

So, every i update something, i do a manual update form my desktop and dont throwing any error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason for this is that Google has updated Node to v15 for the Google Cloud Build environment, but your Google Cloud Functions (GCFs) only support Node to v12 your deploys will fail unless you demote the version of Node in the build environment to Node v12. Here is what I did to fix this in my cloudbuild.yaml:

CHANGED:

`name: "node"`

TO:

`name: node:12`